# $.POST returns 302 status code with blank response

Tags: javascript

I have one field that as currency that is populated on basis of some condition.
I have created a menu_hook and ajax_callback_function which handle the $.POST request.

The request is:

```
$.post('https://www.somedomain.com/module/currency/' + argument1, null function(response) {
//Logic to handle the response
  $('#node_form_formfieldID').html(response);
});
```

But In response I am getting 302 status. Saying 
https://www.somedomain.com/module/currency/11201    302 Found

How to solve this and get the desired response in the form field.

Comment: 302 is a redirect code - is your module redirecting module/currency/% to somewhere else?

Comment: What happens when you access above URL by browser ?

Comment: @Clive - No redirection is set in that module under module/currency

Comment: @2-Stroker- On accessing the above URL I get the response properly.

Comment: 302 indicates a temporary redirect, Ajax related functions wont work properly. Remove redirect or modify URL with the final URL, and also check callback function if it has any redirects. Ajax callback functions should not redirect generally and only echo response back